# How to link two JFrames Windows Together in Java

Tags: java, swing, window, jframe

I am a new Java Programmer and I am tying to link two JFrames Windows together nut I don't know how , can I get some help please.

What I mean is that I made a button and I need the button to go to the next window,
but I don't know how to do so...

Comment: post some code so people can help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to do a wizard then you may want to take a look to [Creating Wizard Dialogs with Java Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/wizard-136789.html) document. You would need only one `JFrame` (or `JDialog`) and several `JPanel` which will pass as you press "Next" button.

If you want open a new window then you can create and show a new `JDialog` within button action listener implementation. Something like this:

```
JButton nextButton = new JButton("Next");
nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.setTitle("Title");
        dialog.setModal(true);
        dialog.getContentPane().add(...); // add components here
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
}
```

Suggested readings:

- [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice) (it's a bad practice)
- [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)
- [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)
- [How to Use Modality in Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html)